# PySpark: combine aggregate and window functions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working with a legacy Spark SQL code like this:

```
SELECT
  column1,
  max(column2),
  first_value(column3),
  last_value(column4)
FROM
  tableA
GROUP BY
 column1
ORDER BY
 columnN
```

I am rewriting it in PySpark as below

```
df.groupBy(column1).agg(max(column2), first(column3), last(column4)).orderBy(columnN)
```

When I'm comparing the two outcomes I can see differences in the fields generated by the first_value/first and last_value/last functions.

Are they behaving in a non-deterministic way when used outside of Window functions?
Can groupBy aggregates be combined with Window functions?

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is possible when you have a wide table and you don't specify ordering for the remaining columns. What happens under the hood is that spark takes `first()` or `last()` row, whichever is available to it as the first condition-matching row on the heap. `Spark SQL` and `pyspark` might access different elements because the ordering is not specified for the remaining columns.

In terms of `Window` function, you can use a `partitionBy(f.col('column_name'))` in your `Window`, which kind of works like a `groupBy` - it groups the data according to a partitioning column. However, without specifying the ordering for all columns, you might arrive at the same problem of non-determinicity. Hope this helps!

For completeness sake, I recommend you have a look at the `pyspark` doc for the `first()` and `last()` functions here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.first

In particular, the following note brings light to why you behaviour was *non-deterministic*:

> Note The function is non-deterministic because its results depends on order of rows which may be non-deterministic after a shuffle.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely !

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

partition = Window.partitionBy("column1").orderBy("columnN")

data = data.withColumn("max_col2", F.max(F.col("column2")).over(partition))\
           .withColumn("first_col3", F.first(F.col("column3")).over(partition))\
           .withColumn("last_col4", F.last(F.col("column4")).over(partition))

data.show(10, False)
```